# Why is sunset in mars blue?

Tags: optics, visible-light, scattering, atmospheric-science, planets

[image]

This is the Martian sunset, as captured by the Spirit rover of NASA. Notice the colors are inverted, i.e. the direct rays blue and diffused rays red, which is exactly the opposite of what you would see on Earth. Isn't red supposed to attenuate less than blue in the atmosphere?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomy_on_Mars#The_color_of_the_sky